# Place annotations in different chart Areas

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart that shows signals in different chart areas, and there is an annotation for each series of the chart to show the data points as the vertical line moves.
My problem is that I want the annotation to be on the graph of each series in every chart area but instead all annotations appear in one chart area as in the picture : [image]

this is the function I have for the annotations :

```
 private void chart1_AnnotationPositionChanging(object sender, AnnotationPositionChangingEventArgs e)
    {
          int i = 0;
          double xv = VA.X;  // VA is a vertical annotation created in another function
             
          foreach (var sig in checkedItems_N) // checkedItems_N contains the Indexes of the items that have been clicked
          {   
              var val = Items[i].Points[pt1].YValues[0];  // Items is a list that contains series that have been clicked
             foreach (var sim in Items[i].Points[pt1].YValues)
              {  
                  anno[i].Y = sim + 0.5; // anno[i] is an array of rectangle annotation
              }
            if (sender == VA) anno[i].X = VA.X;
              anno[i].Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", val); 
              i++;
          }
```

My goal is to change the position of the annotation so that each series in every chart Area to have one annotation on the signal

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation?view=netframework-4.8) : _Set the AxisX, AxisY or both of these annotation properties to the AxisX and AxisY property values of a ChartArea object._